# Visual Studio 2019 Problem in Compile & Proccess Codes (C#)

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2019

I understood that after a Visual Studio 2019 update the timers in C# don't fully work.

In my code below, `label1` is only set to `3` and nothing after happens.
I checked for issues and tested, but I couldn't find the problem

```
private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    Timer1.Start();
}

private void Form1_Enter(object sender, EventArgs e)
{

}

private void Timer1_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
{

    if (Timer1.Interval >2000)
    {
        label1.Text = "2";
    }

    if(Timer1.Interval > 3000)
    {
        label1.Text = "3";
    }
    if(Timer1.Interval > 3999)
    {
        label1.Text = "4";
    }

}
```

Comment: Are you actually modifying `Timer1.Interval` somewhere?

Comment: Hello and welcome to Stack Overflow. The code you show is incomplete. Therefore, we cannot reproduce your issue. Please give us all the necessary code to reproduce the issue (i.e. a [mcve]).

Comment: Are you trying to determine how much time has elapsed? That's not what the `Interval` property is for. Maybe you want a [`Stopwatch`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.diagnostics.stopwatch?view=netframework-4.8)

Comment: Thanks you For replay man no all in normal i test more projects!!!

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. Thank you for taking the time to share your problem. What you asking for is unclear. What is your goal and your difficulty? What have you done so far? Please try to better explain your issue, your development environment and the data structures, as well as to share more code (no screenshot), images or sketches of the screen, and user stories or scenario diagrams. To help you improve your requests, please read the *[How do I ask a good question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)* and **Questions I avoid asking** at the top right.

Comment: I don't understand *I understood that after a Visual Studio 2019 update the timers in C# don't fully work*. What is the interval? Do you change it else it is normal that you get the same thing tick after tick. What is your goal to use a timer? To do something every a certain period or as said by Johnny Mopp?

Comment: Johnny Mopp Before Update Its Everywhere Work!!! But I want
After A time Set text for label1 E.x:After 1 ms set label1 text to 1 After 2 ms set label1 text to 3 ...

Comment: Olivier Rogier E.x:After 1 ms set label1 text to 1 After 2 ms set label1 text to 3 ...

Comment: @wfwe24424r4324 So you need to change the Interval in the code following the condition test, isn't it?

Comment: @Olivier Rogier yes!!

Comment: @wfwe24424r4324 Do you know how to do that or do you need help then can you add rules in your question, please?

Comment: @Olivier Rogier Rules why Rules i Write Sample example no need any rules!!! my codes not any probelm, this problem as VisualStudio

Answer (score 0):

As indicated in your comments, you can do that:

```
private void Timer1_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
  if ( Timer1.Interval > 3999 )
  {
    label1.Text = "4";
    Timer1.Interval = newValue1;
  }
  else
  if ( Timer1.Interval > 3000 )
  {
    label1.Text = "3";
    Timer1.Interval = newValue2;
  }
  else
  if ( Timer1.Interval > 2000 )
  {
    label1.Text = "2";
    Timer1.Interval = newValue3;
  }
  else
    DoSomething();
}
```

I reversed the conditions tests to be coherent and I added some else to optimize and especially to avoid conflicts.

The problem was not with Visual Studio nor a 2019 version nor a Timer but with your code and the algorythm so the rules.

I am not sure of your goal but you can adapt this corrected code.

Comment: Thanks man but before Update My Codes Is Working Why now Not work?

Comment: What does not work? What have you changed? Do you start the timer somewhere? What is the starting interval and for what values do you update?

Comment: before update i not need set Value for interval & Timer Himself change interval value by time pass